# how to change the domain using rails path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So Rails provides these path helpers, for example, I can, in a view file, have

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_admin_article_path(article) %>
```

This would work both in development environment (localhost) or in production environment.
For development, it would generate url

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/articles/1018/edit
```

For production, it would generate

```
http://www.mydomain.com/admin/articles/1018/edit
```

My question is: how do I force the url to always be the production link even in the development environment?  Can I pass a domain value in a hash to the edit_admin_article_path() call?

Thank you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Edit**

For newer version of Rails use

`edit_admin_article_url(article, domain: "example.com")`

**Original answer (Rails 3)**

Try

```
<%= link_to "edit", "http://www.example.com" + edit_admin_article_path(article) %>
```

You could of course refactor the `http://www.example.com` part into a helper method, that way you don't have to keep track of it everywhere if/when you want to change it.

Or you could create an `absolute_link_to` method that does what you want by just wrapping the `link_to` method.

Comment: didnt work for me (I think it would improve the MitM vulnerabilty and there is any security feature in Rails5 which avoids this possible leak of security)

Answer (score 8):

You probably want the url helper, it will take a domain as an option and make a fqdn.

```
edit_admin_article_url(article, domain: "production.tld")
```

It will also pick up any constraints you might have added in the routes.

Comment: I would be nice with a link to some documentation that shows what options can be used. I found the implementation, but it didn't really enlighten me https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2f2c6247f5931982879bebeddf67b30f487e0811/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L134

Comment: Apparently it uses the same options as http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor/url_for